# how to display a table which was generated in model on "tree" type in odoo?

Tags: python-3.x, odoo

A table `A` would be created by function in .py file which is in `pandas.DataFrame` form, for example as below, when I click a button on webside(.xml file):

```
A = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], columns=['a','b'])
```

then I want to display this table `A` on xml as 'tree' type;

> Notes: the size of table `A` is not constant, I mean its columns can be 2, 3, 5 or others.

Comment: Can you get into more detail?

Comment: the table 'A' is created on .py file when click on a button on webside and it has 2 columns, 3 columns or other columns which number is dependent on each calculation; after that I want this table can be shown on  webside or generate an excel report.